# To handle flash messages types dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display flash messages in different styles

i.e for :success message "alert alret-suceess"

I 'm using this code in layout to handle them dynamically

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg,class: "alert alert-#{type}" %>
<% end %>
```

But it works fine for success message giving green background but for "notice" and "alert" types, it gives white background.
I 'm suppose to handle them with if else condition or there is any better way available.

Comment: Do you have `alert alert-notice` and  `alert alert` classes in your stylesheets?

Comment: No I didn't add them, I was unaware of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar approach to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31095573/3259320

**helpers/alert_helper.rb**

```
module AlertHelper
  def build_alert_classes(alert_type)
    classes = 'alert alert-dismissable '
    case alert_type.to_sym 
    when :alert, :danger, :error, :validation_errors
        classes += 'alert-danger'
    when :warning, :todo
        classes += 'alert-warning'
    when :notice, :success
        classes += 'alert-success'
    else 
        classes += 'alert-info'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view, it would become this:

**view**

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: build_alert_classes(type) %>
<% end %>
```